# How to write a button with a link in html?

Tags: html

I wrote the text of this button from html?

```
<form action="link.htm">
    <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you trying to go to for link.htm on click of button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer: You can't.

You can use a `link` tag using `a` tag and add it `href` attribute like this:

```
<a href="your_url">Click</a>
```

**Or** you can use `javascript` like this:

```html
<button onclick="location.href='http://google.com';">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I haven't done html in a while

Comment: `I haven't done html in a while` What do you mean?